# N x M UICompositionalLayout with estimatedWidth for each cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm trying to create this section of the UICollectionView from X when you try to configure your interests. All 3 rows scroll as a together as a group. Here a picture:

[image]

Each item has an estimatedWidth and a fixed Height and the scrolling behaviour is .continuous.
I tried creating vertical groups, horizontal but none of them seem to work.

The best approach I could make was making a vertical group of 3 items but then the separation for each group then becomes the same.

Is this possible to achieve with compositional layouts?

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Is this possible to achieve with compositional layouts?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you search here on SO for `[uicollectionviewcompositionallayout] tags` -- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Buicollectionviewcompositionallayout%5D+tags -- you can find a few examples.